# pdf of X-Y and X/Y with X,Y unif([0,1]), independent (Wasserman: All of Statistics)

Tags: probability, statistics

I am going through Wasserman's All of Statistics book and do not quite understand this problem.

> Let X, Y ~ Uniform(0,1) be independent. Find the PDF for X-Y and X /
> Y.

**The solution given is:**

The joint density of $X, Y$ is

$$ 
f(x, y) = \begin{cases}
1 &\text{if } 0 \leq x \leq 1, 0 \leq y \leq 1 \\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Let $A = X - Y$ The CDF of $A$ is calculated over the area $A_a = \{ (x, y) : x - y \leq a \} $:

$$ F_A(a) = \mathbb{P}(X + Y \leq a) = \int_{A_a} f(x, y)\; dx dy \text{ (this may be a typo, X-Y instead)}$$

*I understand this far. After this I am confused.*

If $0 \leq a \leq 1$, the area is consists of all points in the unit square, othe than the triangle at points $(a, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1 - a)$. Then,

$$ F_A(a) = 1 - \frac{(1 - a)^2}{2} $$

If $-1 \leq a \leq 0$, the area consists of only the points in the triangle $(0, 1), (1 + a, 1), (0, -a)$. Then,

$$ F_A(a) = \frac{(1 + a)^2}{2} $$

Therefore, the PDF is $f_A(a) = F'_A(a)$, or

$$ 
f_A(a) = \begin{cases}
1 + a &\text{if } -1 &lt; a \leq 0 \\
1 - a &\text{if } 0 &lt; a \leq 1 \\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases} 
$$

Why was there a need to split up the area, and why in that fashion? For instance, why does $$0 \leq a \leq 1 \\$$
imply the boundary? I can imagine that this condition is true if $$ X \geq Y $$
... but I do not yet see the area of the triangle given.

Comment: I would have thought $F_A(a) = \mathbb{P}(X - Y \leq a)$ rather than $F_A(a) = \mathbb{P}(X + Y \leq a)$.  You will want to consider $0 < a <1$ separately from $-1<a<0$

Comment: Yes, I think that may be a typo in the answer. I will mark that.

Comment: @Henry Could you explain why the need to consider those two cases? I have a hard time discerning when one should look at cases; does it have to deal with the support?

Comment: You want $Y>X-a$ so for $0 <a < 1$ you can say $\mathbb{P}(X - Y \leq a) = \int\limits_0^a \int\limits_0^1 1\,dy\,dx+  \int\limits_a^1 \int\limits_{x-a}^1 1\,dy\,dx$ or something similar but with $-1<a<0$ you would need different limits on the integral such as  $\mathbb{P}(X - Y \leq a) = \int\limits_0^{1+a} \int\limits_{x-a}^{1} 1\,dy\,dx$